# How to prove that the negation of a false proposition is true?

Tags: logic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTGB9.png)

For #3 I concluded that it's false since t ended up not being in N. So I then have to negate the statement as instructed and prove that the negated proposition is true. I negated the proposition and ended up with "there exists (x,y) in S for any t in N, such that (2x,ty) is not in S". Now how do I prove that this negated proposition is true? I'm thinking that since I started with "(2x,ty) in S implies .... t is not in N) for the original statement, then maybe I should start with "(2x,ty) not in S implies ..." for the negated statement. But I do not know what (2x,ty) not in S implies.

Comment: $(2x,ty) \notin S$ means $y \ne 3x+2$

Comment: I thought of that but that would make t not equal to 2-(2/(3x+2)) which means t can only be greater than 2 and since if t=1 that would make x=0 which is not in N.

Comment: Maybe it is useful to start with some example of elements of $S$... $(1,5), (2,8), (3,11), (4,14), \ldots$.

Comment: Thus, in order to understand if formula 3 is true or false we can consider the first pair: $(1,5)$ and compute the corresponding pair $(2,5t)$. The question is: is there a $t \in \mathbb N$ such that $(2,5t) \in S$? The answer is no, because the only pair starting with $2$ is $(2,8)$ and there is no natural $t$ such that $5t=8$.

Comment: The negation of 3 is $\exists (x,y) \in S \forall t \in \mathbb N (2x,ty) \notin S$. And the example above shows that it is true, because we have found a pair in $S$, the pair $(1,5)$, such that the corresponding $(2x,ty)$ will be: $(2,5t)$ that does not satisfy the condition defining $S$ because $5t=3\times 2+2=8$ has no solutions in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: *Conclusion*: "How to prove that the negation of a false proposition is true?" If we have proved that a proposition is False, this is exactly what we need to prove that its negation is True.